# Why is this working in a normal for loop but not a range based for loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop, c++11, stdvector, range-based-loop

```
void set_fee(Patron p, int fee)
{
    for (Patron x : patrons)
    {
        if (p.get_name() == x.get_name()) x.set_fee(fee);
    }
    
    for (int i = 0; i < patrons.size(); i++)
    {
        if (patrons[i].get_name() == p.get_name()) patrons[i].set_fee(fee);
    }
}
```

So `patron` is just some class I made and none of the functions here really matter `get_name()` just returns the object's name and `set_fee(fee)` just sets the `fee` of the object to fee.

But does anyone have any idea for why the first loop doesn't work but the second one does? I basically just wanna look for `p` inside the `patrons` vector and once I find it I want to change the fee of the patron object inside the vector, but the first way doesn't work, why?

Comment: You probably want reference instead of copy: `for (Patron& x : patrons)`

Comment: @yaelreshet11 The copy constructor may be working just fine, but `x.set_fee(fee);` is not working on the object you have in `patrons` but on the copy you have in `x`.

Comment: @yaelreshet11 No, it probably means that the copy constructor works. If you modify a copy, it's typically desirable that only the copy is affected and not the object that was copied from.

Comment: Also note that if `p` does not change inside the function, you can pass by `const` reference: `void set_fee(Patron const& p, int fee)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `x` in the range based for loop is a copy of the element in the vector. You need to have reference there

```
for (Patron& x : patrons)
//   ^^^^^^^^
{
   // ....
}
```

or else `x.set_fee(fee);` will be called on the *copy*.

Comment: Ohhhhhh right yeah thanks got it

Comment: @JeJo Cheers! :-)